# Support multiple resource IDs with Spring OAuth

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory

**Situation.** We are using Spring OAuth to validate a security token (JWT). The token has an `aud` claim for a particular resource ID. The following code correctly validates any JWT tokens signed with an aud claim containing the client ID `resourceId-123`:

```java
class ResourceServerConfig {

  @Bean
  protected ResourceServerConfiguration adminResources2() {
    ResourceServerConfiguration resource = new ResourceServerConfiguration() {
      void setConfigurers(List<ResourceServerConfigurer> configurers) {
        super.setConfigurers(configurers)
      }
    }
    resource.setConfigurers(Collections.<ResourceServerConfigurer>singletonList(new ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {
      @Override
      void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId("resourceId-123")
      }

      @Override
      void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/path")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
      }
    }))

    resource.setOrder(3)
    return resource
  }
}
```

**Question.** How can we support multiple Client IDs for the same path (in this example above, `/path`)? I have seen examples of how to configure multiple Beans with different client IDs for *different* API paths, but I want to protect this resource with 2+ client IDs. Any examples or documentation of how this could be done? Or are we trying to do something fundamentally incorrect?

Comment: May I know why you will need more than one client app? Will your web app be used by users from different tenants?

Comment: @JackJia for the time being, we only need to support users from a single tenant.

Comment: This sounds odd to me. An API shouldn't have multiple client ids.

Comment: Thanks @juunas - do you know if this is a Microsoft-specific way to think about authentication, or this is an OAuth standard?

Comment: Have you checked with filters / interceptors ?

Comment: @HakunaMatata in what sense? Implementing a custom filter is beyond what we'd be willing to do.

Comment: @Kon Did you tried this? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/tests/annotation/multi/src/main/java/demo/Application.java

Comment: @Siddhesh yes, as mentioned above. Thank you for checking, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're going about it the wrong way.

The client ID isn't the same as the audience in Spring Security, rather a client is allowed one or more resource Ids and the JWT may contain multiple audiences.

So I think you should follow the example where you have different resource Ids for different paths, create a new resource ID for the shared paths and add to all the clients that are allowed to access it.

Example:

Paths:

```
|----------------+-------------|
| Path           | Resource ID |
|----------------+-------------|
| /client1/info  | client1     |
| /client2/info  | client2     |
| /shared/status | all-clients |
|----------------+-------------|
```

Clients:

```
|---------+----------------------|
| Client  | Resource IDs         |
|---------+----------------------|
| client1 | client1, all-clients |
| client2 | client2, all-clients |
|---------+----------------------|
```

It'd be easier to show something if you could provide a runnable example I could tinker with, but with the limited amount of code you have posted this is the best I can do.

Another way to go about it is to use different scopes instead of different audiences. That would remove the need for mulitple resource server configurations and you could instead use an expression like `#oauth2.hasScope('admin')` in `.access()` or in `@PreAuthorize`.